# shell variable not exported from subshell?

Tags: command-line, bash, gnome-shell

While going through learn bash the hard way , I found that `subshells` inherits variables from their parent and they can overwrite it within their own scope.
and it won't be reflected to the parent shell unless we use `export`,

I tried the below example for exporting VAR1 , and I am not getting the VAR1 value reflected to my parent shell.
Can someone please explain If I am missing something here ,
Thanks in Advance.

```
anupam:~$ VAR1="variable under shell $$.pid and $BASHPID.bashid"
anupam:~$ set -o posix; set | grep -i VAR1
VAR1='variable under shell 6137.pid and 6137.bashid'
anupam:~$ (
> echo Inside the subshell
> echo ${VAR1}
> VAR1="variable under subshell with $$.pid and $BASHPID.bashid"
> echo ${VAR1}
> )
Inside the subshell
variable under shell 6137.pid and 6137.bashid
variable under subshell with 6137.pid and 6193.bashid
anupam:~$ set -o posix; set | grep -i VAR1
VAR1='variable under shell 6137.pid and 6137.bashid'
anupam:~$ (
> echo Inside another subshell
> echo ${VAR1}
> VAR1="variable under another subshell with $$.pid and $BASHPID.bashid"
> echo ${VAR1}
> export VAR1="exported variable under another subshell with $$.pid and $BASHPID.bashid"
> )
Inside another subshell
variable under shell 6137.pid and 6137.bashid
variable under another subshell with 6137.pid and 6208.bashid
anupam:~$ set -o posix; set | grep -i VAR1
VAR1='variable under shell 6137.pid and 6137.bashid'
anupam:~$
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A child cannot change the environment of the parent. You can export variables from parent to children, not vice versa.

Comment: Thanks @choroba , does it mean that I can't change the shell variables / environment variables from other external commands like Python subprocess.

Comment: Not directly. You can send a value from a child process via IPC and use it in the parent script, though.